# Append message to MAM channel

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging

I can create a MAM channel and add message to it in a single script using the [doc](https://docs.iota.org/docs/mam/1.0/tutorials/js/create-public-channel). But when I want to add more message(in another script) to same channel later, I need to have following details saved from first script

- seed
- first root(required to fetch all the messages when needed)
- mamState.channel.next_root
- mamState.channel.start

As of my understanding from documentation, I need to save seed and first root to add more message to same channel later. But when I execute the example code, I couldn't find a way to add more messages to same channel using seed and first root.

And I can add more messages to same channel using seed, mamState.channel.next_root and mamState.channel.start.

Should I save seed, mamState.channel.next_root and mamState.channel.start in database to add more messages to same channel later?

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I do not hold a direct answer, I am sorry.

What I would like to add is that MAM is going to be deprecated with the [upcoming Chrysalis Part 2 upgrade](https://blog.iota.org/chrysalis-iota-1-5-phase-1-now-live-on-mainnet-958ec4a4a415), therefore I suggest you look into IOTA Streams, that will take over MAM:

Read about the latest news in our Blog here:
https://blog.iota.org/iota-streams-update-september-2020-c3b8668e231e